# Keras Classifier returns similar output for all Predictions

Tags: neural-network, keras, dataset

I completed training the model with an accuracy of 1.000 and a validation accuracy of 0.9565. Unfortunately whenever i input a image into my model i get the same output regardless. Am i doing something wrong when predicting or during my training. W and A are my class labels.

My folder structure for the image generators are as follows:

images/

a/
   a001.jpg.png..
 w/
   w002.jpg.png..

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 64

# this is a generator that will read pictures found in
# subfolers of 'data/train', and indefinitely generate
# batches of augmented image data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\Zahid\\Desktop\\Dataset\\train',  # this is the target directory
    target_size=(150, 150),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary')  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels

# this is a similar generator, for validation data
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\Zahid\\Desktop\\Dataset\\val',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Zahid\\Desktop\\Data\\TrainingData\\images\\a\\img_0201.jpg.png")
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (150, 150))
x = img_to_array(resized_image)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
x = x/255
print(x.shape)
scores_train = model.predict(x)
print(scores_train)
```

Comment: what is number 1 in your last dense layer? Do you have only one class? and why you use a sigmoid function in the output layer? try using softmax function, it is better.

Comment: @honas.cs I Have two classes as mentioned in the question , and i followed a keras example to train this model. As shown in my folder structure i have seperated the classes into two seperate folders and trained them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using sigmoid as activation function in last layer. It will output generate output based on if probability above 50% then it belongs to "W" class and if it is less than 50% belongs to "A" class.
If you can print output probability of different images & share it then it will little helpful for us for understand problem

Comment: The output probability remains the same regardless of the image at 3.2287784e-15.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by changing the Dense Layer to 2  hence specifying two classes, and also switching the Sigmoid activation function with a Softmax function.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide by 255 in the prediction make sure that the datatype is float and not int or unsigned int.
Make sure to implicitly convert the image x to float and divide by 255.0 before prediction. In other words make sure that you array is not all 0. You can still use Sigmoid for binary classifica with 1 dense layer. It should work